# Return output from an MsBuild task?

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task

I'd like to calculate a path in a MsBuild task, to be used by another MsBuild task.
What is the best way to accomplish this?

Setting a environment variable, printing to Console, ...?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Use a property or an item. Your MSBuild that calculates the path, return it as a property and you use this property as input for your other task.

```cs
public class CalculatePathTask : ITask
{
    [Output]
    public String Path { get; set; }

    public bool Execute()
    {                                   
        Path = CalculatePath();

        return true;
    }
}
```

```xml
<Target Name="CalculateAndUsePath">
  <CalculatePathTask>
    <Output TaskParameter="Path" PropertyName="CalculatePath"/>
  </CalculatePathTask>

  <Message Text="My path is $(CalculatePath)"/>
</Target>
```

If you need to pass a value between two MSBuild project, you should create a third one that will call the other using MSBuild Task and use the **TargetOutputs** element to get back the value that you want.

Comment: just a short note: In my case `ItemName` was not working. As soon as I changed it to `PropertyName` it worked like a charm.

Comment: Tried this but got `The "TaskParameter" parameter is not supported by the "MyCustomTask" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a settable public instance property.`

Comment: @jpierson too late but for the future: maybe you forgot to mark the attribute as [Output] in the task.