# Msbuild Custom Task - For loop

Tags: c#, msbuild

I would like to implement a Msbuild Custome task to loop a list of items and do something about each item. Basically I would liketo build a foreach or for loop in msbuild.

I have searched around but didn't find much useful information about output a list of items and loop though each of them

What I got

How to implement Custom Tasks 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2006/01/21/515834.aspx

Return output from a custom msbuild task

[Return output from an MsBuild task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372997/return-output-from-an-msbuild-task)

Is it possible to implement my though with msbuild custom task?

Update:

I would like something

```
<Foreach item='String' in="PropertyGroups" Property='MyPropertyName'>
   //do what ever to use $(MypropertyName) for other tasks
</Foreach>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard MSBuild tasks operate on collections (ItemGroup in MSBuild-ese, ITaskItem[] in the ITask interface) and custom tasks can do the same. You don't need a foreach.

Your task, if you need a custom task, would look like this:

```
<MyTask TaskItems="@(blah)"/>
```

Comment: @icn - Even more specific. Ignore the foreach concept, what are you trying to do for your build.