# Why is this output parameter empty?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, msbuild, msbuild-task

I have a task with an output parameter:

```
public class HelloWorld
    : Task
{
    [Output]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public override bool Execute()
    {
        Log.LogWarning("HelloWorld task entry");

        Log.LogWarning("Setting 'Message'");
        this.Message = "Hello World!";
        Log.LogWarning("Set 'Message' to '{0}'", this.Message);

        Log.LogWarning("HelloWorld task exit");
        return true;
    }
}
```

I execute this task in another project:

```
<UsingTask TaskName="HelloWorld" AssemblyFile="path to dll" />
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <HelloWorld>
        <Output TaskParameter="Message" PropertyName="Message" />
    </HelloWorld>
    <Warning Text="HelloWorld task has finished" />
    <Warning Text="Message: @(Message)" />
</Target>
```

This is the build output:

> warning : HelloWorld task entry
>   warning : Setting 'Message'
>   warning : Set 'Message' to 'Hello World!'
>   warning : HelloWorld task exit
>   warning : HelloWorld task has finished
>   warning : Message:

Why is the `Message` output parameter empty?

Comment: Have you tried `<Warning Text="Message: $Message" />`?

Comment: or `<Warning Text="Message: $(Message)" />`?

Comment: You might want to have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372997/return-output-from-an-msbuild-task

Comment: @Haukinger your version works. I guess I got confused while reading various examples. I'll VTC this as a duplicate instead of a typo; while it's technically a typo I think it may help future readers.